# How would you say "talking shop" in Japanese?

Tags: translation, slang

In English, when we say someone is "talking shop", we mean that they are having a conversation about a particular trade or skill that they're familiar with (usually because it's their profession), with someone else who is equally familiar with it. In this kind of conversation people use the language they normally would while working (i.e. they wouldn't use layman's terms or dumb-down their word choice like they would when talking to someone outside the profession). When people are talking shop, it is (by definition) rather hard to understand by someone who doesn't know about said profession.

Is there anything similar to "talking shop" in Japanese, while keeping the slangy tone?

Comment: please give an example or context. also lang-8 or http://esaura.cc are good for these type of questions.

Comment: I've never heard of "talking shop", is that a phrase used in a specific area or region?

Comment: @Chris: I wondered if it was specific to a country(ies) but seems not: eg Apple JE dictionary: talk shop
｟略式｠（時所を選ばず）自分の仕事［職業, 商売］の話ばかりする.

Comment: @Tim Interesting. I asked some other people if they had heard of it, but none had. Is it old?

Comment: The Urban Dictionary definition of "talking shop" is [here](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=talking+shop)

Comment: @Chris: Been around for a long time and still current.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there isn't. You will have to think of an alternative. For example:

仕事の話をする

> AさんとBさんはいつも仕事の話ばかりする
>
> A and B are always talking shop (talking about work).

専門の話をする

> この2人が専門の話をしている
>
> These two are talking shop.

Comment: [The tatoeba project](http://tangorin.com/examples/talking%20shop) confirms it (the example about the doctors).

Answer (score 5):

How about 専門談義{せんもんだんぎ}?

- 専門: speciality, professional
- 談義: discourse, preachment, conversation

It's not exactly a slang, but not listed in a dictionary either. Its connotation can be positive, neutral or negative, depending on the context and the following predicate.

> 2人の医者が専門談義にふけっていた。
>
> Two doctors were talking shop.

By changing the first half of the compound, you can be specific about which field, but may lose the 'professionally related' aspect:

> 参加者はパソコン談義に花を咲かせていました。

Answer (score -1):

I just found a word meaning shop talk:

> [楽屋落]{がくやお}ち

It can also mean: matters incomprehensible to outsiders, inside joke, private joke
http://tangorin.com/general/inside%20joke

Comment: As you said, 楽屋落ち means an inside _joke_, and it is different from a shop talk.  (落ち means a punchline of a joke.)

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto the site says it also means shop talk

Comment: I see, but then the site is wrong.  楽屋落ち only means an inside joke.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto that you know of, but who knows. I'd be interested to see what other users have to say.

Comment: 落ち means a punchline of a joke (as I said), and 楽屋落ち is a special kind of 落ち.  But if you do not follow this logic, then it is fine for me.  Who cares.